# When building ebpf I get "unknown target triple 'bpf', please use -triple or -arch"

Tags: llvm-clang, ebpf

I have just started experimenting with XDP in an VM. I tried to build for bpf and I face an error, how can I resolve this?

```
   # clang -O2 -Wall -target bpf -c all_dropper.c -o dropper.o
   error: unknown target triple 'bpf', please use -triple or -arch
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue is resolved, I had to upgrade the clang version to 3.9.

Comment: I am unable to update the clang version more than 3.4 on centos. can you help out. how did you upgrade your 'clang' package? Thanks